# How are git repositories used by Snakemake via kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, snakemake

The Snakemake documentation here:

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cloud.html

states the following under the section heading "Executing a Snakemake workflow via kubernetes":

> Currently, this mode requires that the Snakemake workflow is stored in a git repository. Snakemake uses git to query necessary source files (the Snakefile, scripts, config, …) for workflow execution and encodes them into the kubernetes job.

This is confusing to me.  Looking at the example command line given:

```
snakemake --kubernetes --use-conda --default-remote-provider $REMOTE --default-remote-prefix $PREFIX
```

I don't see any reference to a git repository.  It seems to me that Snakemake will look for the snakefile on the local host, in the working directory where this command is issued from.  What is this business about a git repository?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured this out.  In the tutorials included with the documentation they clone a github repository that contains the snakefile and other related files.  For example, in this tutorial:

https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executor_tutorial/google_lifesciences.html

The command is:

```
git clone https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-lsh-tutorial-data
```

And if you do an `ls -a` command in the directory that gets created you'll see .git and .github subdirectories, and also a file .gitpod.yml.  Apparently `snakemake --kubernetes` uses these, and if they aren't there with the snakefile the command will fail.

Comment: Interestingly, I do find that if I move just the snakefile and environment files to a separate directory then snakemake --kubernetes will execute happily.  But the following warning is generated:

Comment: `Unable to retrieve additional files from git. This is not a git repository.` Apparently snakemake first tries to use git to collect necessary files, but if it discovers the working directory is not a git repository then it will just look for the snakefile without git.  In my experience, the jobs are deployed successfully by kubernetes, so it doesn't seem that a git repository is strictly required in the current version of Snakemake.